# Why does Chrome warn of XSS, is this due to evaluate?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xss

An API I'm working with is returning valid JSON inside of `();`. I asked the maintainer why, they said `JSONP` was implemented to prevent XSS warnings in the browser.

What kind of Javascript triggers this warning? Would this be an `eval` or an `alert`?

Comment: I think JSONP is implemented because the API maintainer is too lazy to learn about and deal with CORS

Comment: Note that just adding `();` doesn't convert JSON to JSON-P, there'd need to be the name of a function too, and then your JS would need to define that function.

Comment: @nnnn I understand, thank you. @Jaromanda X, what would trigger XSS is what I'm trying to figure out, that a `();` around a JSON Array would make the warning go away?